# Bootstrap and cmd's SUBST function just collided and destroyed my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, windows-xp

So, I'm on Win XP (Macs are expensive, alright?) and I found [this link](http://www.artofbi.com/index.php/2010/04/windows-command-prompt-shorten-directory-length-trick/) which made my life SO much easier. I changed my path from:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\DevAdmin\rails_projects\arcwmi_reports>
```

to

```
R:\arcwmi_reports>
```

So much nicer!

But, when I went to create a new project and I added `@import "bootstrap"` to my custom.css.scss file, I suddenly got this error on my site:

```
Showing R:/arcwmi_reports/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised: 
different prefix: "C:/" and "R:/arcwmi_reports/app/assets/stylesheets"
(in R:/arcwmi_reports/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
```

Here's line #5:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
```

I know this line is the problem because if I comment it out, or the `@import "bootstrap"` then my stuff works fine.

One of those lines of code is trying to use the old prefix. I don't know which.

What is going on here?!??!

Thanks -Chip

Comment: So the issue is that I started my rails server on the R:\ substitute and for some reason the stylesheet_link_tag conflicted with the server request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is that I started my rails server on the R:\ substitute and for some reason the stylesheet_link_tag conflicted with the server request.

As soon as I shut down the server and re-started it using the full path, the page loads fine.

I don't know why this creates such a conflict, but it seems the server catches the error and won't load the page.

This is a rubber duck moment, I guess.